# Contour intergals of rational fuction

Tags: contour-integration, residue-calculus

Consider $$F=\frac {x}{x^3+y^3}dx+\frac{y}{x^3+y^3}dy$$

1) Show that $\int_GF=0$, where $G$ is the arc of a circle or radius $r$ in the first quadrant.

2) Compute the integral of $F$ along the segment connecting $(0,1)$ with $(1,0)$

**Attempt:**

1) $G$ has the parameterization $y=\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$

$$\int_G\frac {x}{x^3+y^3}dx+\frac{y}{x^3+y^3}dy=\int_0^r\frac {x}{x^3+\sqrt{r^2-x^2}^3}dx+\frac{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}{x^3+\sqrt{r^2-x^2}^3}\frac{x}{-\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}dx=0$$

2) The segment $I$ has parameterization $y=1-x$. Then

$$\int_I\frac {x}{x^3+y^3}dx+\frac{y}{x^3+y^3}dy=\int_0^1\frac {x}{x^3+(1-x)^3}dx-\frac{(1-x)}{x^3+(1-x)^3}dx=\int_0^1\frac {2x-1}{x^3+(1-x)^3}dx=\int_0^1\frac {2x-1}{3x^2-3x+1}dx$$

How can we proceed? Can we use the residue theorem?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_rational_functions#Integrands_of_the_form_xm_.2F_.28a_x2_.2B_b_x_.2B_c.29n

Comment: I think the first part can use Green formula.

Answer (score 1):

1)$$F=\frac{1}{x^3+y^3}\frac{1}{2}d(x^2+y^2)$$
In polar coordinates it becomes
$$\frac{1}{\cos^3(\theta)+\sin^3(\theta)}\frac{dr^2}{2r^3}=\frac{1}{\cos^3(\theta)+\sin^3(\theta)}\frac{dr}{r^2}$$
You get $0$ just by "integrating" the radial part.

2) If you integrate on the segment between $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ you are integrating on the line $y=1-x$:
$$F=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d(2x^2-2x+1)}{3x^2-3x+1}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{3}\frac{d(3x^2-3x+1)}{3x^2-3x+1}=\frac{1}{3}d\ln|3x^2-3x+1|\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\frac{2x-1}{3x^2-3x+1}=\frac{1}{3}\frac{6x-3}{3x^2-3x+1}=\frac{1}{3}(\ln|3x^2-3x+1|)'
\end{align*}