# Double integral of a rational function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Consider the region $D$ given by $1\leq x^2+y^2\leq2\land0\leq y\leq x$. Compute $$\iint_D\frac{xy(x-y)}{x^3+y^3}dxdy$$

**Attempt:** The region $D$ is part of a ring in the first quadrant below the line $y=x$

Any hints are wellcome.

Comment: Try to reduce it to two integrals of one variable.

Comment: have you tried polar coordinates? It seems there's enough circular simmetry to be able to try that, even though I'm not sure the trigonometric integral that comes out is going to be that nice...

Comment: Don't you think this question is duplicated??http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/867853/contour-intergals-of-rational-fuction

Comment: How are they connected? @Shine

Comment: @Student, Use the Green formula. But the region of the integral is different.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you elaborate on that? @Shine

Comment: $\oint \frac{x}{x^3+y^3}dx+\frac{y}{x^3+y^3}dy= \int \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\frac{y}{x^3+y^3})-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\frac{x}{x^3+y^3})dxdy=\int \frac{-3xy(x-y)}{(x^3+y^3)^2} dxdy $

Comment: Hi student. Remember, if you feel someone answered your question properly, to accept an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing to polar coordinates, $x=\rho \cos\theta$, $y=\rho \sin\theta$, and the Jacobian of the transformation is $J=\rho$. Then:
$$\int_1^\sqrt2 \rho d\rho\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{\sin\theta\cos\theta(\cos\theta-\sin\theta)}{\cos^3\theta+\sin^3\theta}d\theta$$
The first integral is immediate and yields $\frac{1}{2}$, so we'll multiply the answer given by the trigonometric integral by one half. For the trigonometric integral, let's use the substitution $u=\cos^3\theta +\sin^3\theta$, $du=(-3\cos^2\theta\sin\theta+3\sin^2\theta\cos\theta)d \theta=-3(\cos^2\theta\sin\theta-\sin^2\theta\cos\theta)d\theta$. The integral becomes:
$$-\frac{1}{3}\int_1^\frac{\sqrt2}{2}\frac{du}{u}=-\frac{1}{3}\log u\bigg|_{u=1}^{u=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}}=-\frac{1}{3} \log \frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$$
Multiplying by one half yields $I=-\frac{1}{6} \log \frac{\sqrt 2}{2}=\frac{\log 2}{12}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$x=r\cos \phi$$
$$y=r\sin \phi$$
$$J=r$$

$$\int_{0}^{\pi /4}\int_1^{\sqrt2}\frac{r^4\cos \phi \sin \phi (\cos \phi - \sin \phi)}{r^3(\cos^3 \phi + \sin^3 \phi)}drd\phi=$$

Can you take it from here?